# Is there a way to change my AWS Lambda Function response to a JSON format?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, aws-lambda

I am trying to change the format of my Lambda function to Json so that my Javascript can read it in .Json, however i can't seem to find any information on how to do it without causing me any problems to my function.
My Lambda function works fine and it connects to my API gateway perfectly, the only problem is the Json.
Anyone got any guesses on what i need to do?

This is the error that i receive when i do try that.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Object of type set is not JSON serializable",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 18, in lambda_handler\n    return json.dumps({int(response[\"Attributes\"][\"visits\"][\"N\"])})\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py\", line 231, in dumps\n    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py\", line 199, in encode\n    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py\", line 257, in iterencode\n    return _iterencode(o, 0)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py\", line 179, in default\n    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '\n"
  ]
}
```

Python code:

```
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
    response = dynamodb.update_item (
        TableName='resumecount', 
        Key= {
          'url':{'S': "lewispeterson.com"}
        },
    
        UpdateExpression = 'SET visits = visits + :inc',
        ExpressionAttributeValues = {
            ':inc': {'N': '1'}
        },
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )

    print("UPDATING ITEM")

return json.dumps({int(response["Attributes"]["visits"]["N"])})
```

---

```
{
 "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"192\""
}
```

Comment: Sorry didn't mention what Json i used for my lambda function:  
return json.dumps({int(response["Attributes"]["visits"]["N"])}).    
I want to be able to get this information from Lambda to be fetched from my Javascript.